# Why, in a discrete-time quantum walk,we first apply the tensor product of the coin operation with the identity?

Tags: quantum-walks

When we apply coin step in the quantum walk, for example considering the H gate, we first do it's tensor product with Identity vector of the position Hilbert space. Why is this so? Please see below statement for more details:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You started with the state $|\psi \rangle = |0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle $ which belongs to the space $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$. To operate state on this space, your operator must also have the same dimension. Thus, you need to have $H \otimes I$ and not just $H$ if you want to operate the Hadamard gate $H$ on the first qubit. Operations on qubits are just matrix multiplication after all so you need to make sure you have the correct dimensionality. In this case, $H \otimes I$ does that. It makes sure you have the right dimension along with doing exactly what you were looking to do, by applying $H$ to the first qubit and leave the second qubit alone.

---

To be more explicit, we have the state $|00\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. The Hadamard gate, $H$, can be written in the computational basis as $H = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $.  We can't apply $H$ to the state $|00\rangle$ directly, since the there is a mismatched in the dimensionality. However,
$$ H \otimes  I =  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \otimes   \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &  1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} $$
Now they have the same dimension, and if you apply this to the state $|00\rangle$, we have

\begin{align} (H\otimes I) (|0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle) &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &  1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  =  \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\otimes|0\rangle 
\end{align}

Now,  the above is the explicit way of writing out the operation in matrix form  but as you can see, it is cumbersome and a lot more work than necessary. So often, we use the [linear mapping property of tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps), which tells us that  $$(H\otimes I) (|0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle) = H \big(|0\rangle \big) \otimes I \big( |0\rangle \big) = \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \otimes |0\rangle $$

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: In your explanation, you have choosen the Identity matrix of 2*2.  But if we have k-dimensional vector, what would be the size of Identity matrix?

Comment: The size of the Idenity matrix will be $2^{k-1} \times 2^{k-1} $ then. Notice how it always in the power of 2.

Answer (score 1):

A (discrete-time) *quantum walk* can be thought of as the direct "quantization" of a classical random walk.

In a classical random walk, at each iteration, you flip a coin and move the walker in a direction conditionally to the result of the coin flip.

The quantum generalisation of this is to think of the "coin" as a "coin state", that is, a qubit, and to make the "coin flip" into a similarly unbiased quantum gate (although one can generalises this to allow for arbitrary quantum gates as coin operations).

The "coin operation" gate must therefore, by conception, be an operation *that only affects the coin space*. In your notation, a state such as $|0\rangle\otimes|0\rangle$ lives in the coin+walker space, with the first space being the coin space. It follows that to act locally on the coin space amounts to perform a local operation of the form $U\otimes I$.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that by applying Hadamard just to the coin and doing nothing to the position state, this is the equivalent of tossing the coin.

To see this in a very crude way, imagine applying Hadamard to a qubit in the state $|0\rangle$. You get a state $(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ which, if we were to measure it, would be equivalent to a coin giving heads or tails with 50:50 probability.

The shift operator then says "depending on whether the coin is in heads or tails, update the position register appropriately".